# Make toolbar only transparant in one activity/fragment

Tags: android

I need my toolbar to be transparant but only in one activity/fragment.
I know that this is the way to do it:

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

But it changes the toolbar also for the other fragments. Is there an alternative or a way to make it only applicable for one fragment.

This way I need to set the toolbar's alpha back in every activity/fragment.:

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
```

Is this the only way or?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could use themes:

```
<style name="my.ToolbarActivity" parent="base">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
</style>

<style name="my.ToolbarActivity.Overlay" parent="my.ToolbarActivity">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="my.ToolbarActivity.Overlay.Transparent" parent="my.ToolbarActivity.Overlay">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.TransparentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/my.ToolbarActivity.Overlay.Transparent"
        ....
  </activity
  <activity
        android:name=".activity.OverlayActivity"
        android:theme="@style/my.ToolbarActivity.Overlay"
        ...
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fragment control flow within an activity is such that you have a standard switch fragment function defined as below, then its pretty obvious  -

```
public void switchfragment(){
     switch(fragment_number){
         case 1:
            hideActionBar() ; // or hideToolbar() as u want
            return new Fragment1();
         case 2:
            showActionBar();  //or showtoolbar() as u want
            return new Fragment2();
}

}
```

I dont see a case when you would have to go and set it from within indivisual fragments unless you try to switch fragment from within a fragment which I generally avoid.